# C++ std::sort on vector<object*> - Assignment of Read-only Location

Tags: c++, stdvector

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

With my particular problem, the sort call was inside a Render function marked as const.  By either removing the const (not my preference) or putting the sort in another function (in this case, the bottom of my Update), the problem is taken care of.  As several answerer's suggested, it WAS a const problem, just not where I was looking!

---

**ORIGINAL PROBLEM**

I have an std::vector list of pointers to objects declared thus:

```
std::vector<Object*> myObjects;
```

I'm trying to sort them by a member data through a getter...  I have a sort predicate as well.  Here's the sort predicate followed by the std::sort call:

```
bool SortByDistance(const Object* o1, const Object* o2)
{
    return o1->GetDist() < o2->GetDist();
}
```

Sort call:

```
std::sort(myObjects.begin(), myObjects.end(), SortByDistance);
```

I'm getting a dozen or so errors though complaining about assignment of read-only location or similar:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2385: error: assignment of read-only location
```

I'm sure it is something silly I'm doing...  could someone help shed some light?  I'm rusty with my C++ and just getting back into it!  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I'm still getting the same error, despite trying iammilind's suggestions to remove the const altogether or ensure that const is 100% (in other words, I've tried adding const to the end of the SortByDistance predicate, as well as removing it from the situation altogether.

I'm thinking one of the commenters may be onto something by suggestion I am doing something stupid and dangerous: storing raw pointers to objects in STL containers.  I've never done this any differently though... what are the reasons for storing objects in containers that aren't dynamically allocated on the heap?  I assume if I'm not dealing with raw pointers, a lot of the complexity of my sort problem goes away.

I'm currently creating my Objects like this:

```
std::vector<Object*> myObjects;
Object* tempObject = new Object;
myObjects.push_back(tempObject);
```

I of course release that memory when the program finishes, but it sounds like this is just a bad idea in general?

On a more related note (to the question I asked), here's the code in stl_algo.h that is complaining:

```
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Compare>
void
__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
         _RandomAccessIterator __last, _Compare __comp)
{
  if (__first == __last) return;

  for (_RandomAccessIterator __i = __first + 1; __i != __last; ++__i)
{
  typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type
    __val = *__i;
  if (__comp(__val, *__first))
    {
      std::copy_backward(__first, __i, __i + 1);
      *__first = __val;  // this line is the one complaining about read-only assignment
    }
  else
    std::__unguarded_linear_insert(__i, __val, __comp);
}
}
```

Despite trying various const/no-const solutions, I still get the same error.  If I comment out the line that is running the sort:
    std::sort(myObjects.begin(), myObjects.end(), SortByDistance);
the errors, of course, go away.

Comment: Is `GetDist()` a member of `Object` or a member of a class that derives from `Object`?

Comment: what's at stl_algo.h line 2385?

Comment: Ugh! Raw pointers in STL containers!

Comment: As a clarification on Billy ONeal's comment - If you're not using the raw pointers to own their objects, then its fine (and often the correct thing to do). If they're used for ownership things get a lot more scary...

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code for your question, i.e. at least Object::GetDist().

Comment: GetDist is a member of Object - sorry, great question.

Comment: Here's Object::GetDist(): float GetDist() const                    { return m_camDist; }

Comment: Michael: I do believe I am using them for ownership...  I actually do this quite frequently.  It's a little off-topic, but I would sure love to hear why this is problematic and what a better solution would be.  Like I said, I am admittedly rusty with C++ coming off a 5-year web development startup, so getting back into a much more natural OOP setting is (great but) slow :)

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I'm doing:  std::vector<Object*> myObjects;  then pushing objects on it like: Object* tempObject = new Object;  myObjects.push_back(tempObject);

Comment: Thomas, stl_algo.h is complaining about this line: `*__first = __val;`   which is in the following context:  `template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Compare>
    void
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from your code, I guess that your `Object::GetDist()` method is not `const`. In C++, a `const` object of a `class` can call only `const` members.
If this is the case then you have 2 ways to remove this error.

(1) Make `GetDist` as `const`:

```
class Object {
  int GetDist () const;  // <-- add const
};
```

(2) Change `SortByDistance`:

```
bool SortByDistance (Object*, Object*); // <-- remove const
```

Comment: I think I've actually tried both solutions previously...  let me try again and I'll get back with you.  That does make a ton of sense... maybe I forgot something trivial when attempting the theory!

Comment: Yeah, must be something else I'm not thinking of that is still causing trouble.  If I set GetDist to const: `int GetDist() const;` I still get the error.  If I set SortByDistance to not have any const (and consequently leave GetDist to not be const) I get the exact same error. Only thing I can think of is that this is just bad practice with pointers in STL containers like this.  Is there something else I should check that might cause problems?

Comment: @David, It's better to update the error in your question and inform to me in this comment section.

Comment: iammilind: I updated the original question with situation after running through some const variations.  I also tried to take a step back and give you an idea of why I am doing things the way I am in the first place...  maybe there is just a better way, and this simply won't work?  This is in Xcode 4.2beta btw for iPhone/iPad development.  Compliler: LLVM GCC 4.2.

Comment: I am going to mark immilind's response as the correct answer, as I think that would solve the problem in most cases.  It didn't for me, but I think that is because of something unique I am doing.  If I figure out a solution, I'll repost it here.

Comment: @David, thanks, I had by the way thought about your code along with STL for around 30 mins yesterday; but couldn't figure out that why it's not working even after removal of `const`. Note that `STL`  code is standard and cannot cause such error so often without `const`ness inside it.

Comment: AHA!  I figured it out!  The problem with my specific set of code was that the Render function which housed the sort call was marked as const.  Yet another great example of where the surrounding code is more pertinent than you might think!  Thanks again to everyone who took a look at this for me.  I'll update the question with this insight.

Comment: @David, Good that you found out. `const` was my first suspect as it can be seen in my answer and comments.